# How does Dynamic DNS know when to update IP address in the Dynamic DNS provider?

Tags: dns

When exactly does a Dynamic DNS client update IP on the Dynamic DNS provider?

Is it possible that for some short period of time (after the IP from the ISP has changed) the DNS hostname would not be linked to the correct IP?

Comment: NE is a site for network professionals to ask and provide answers about professional networks. This question seems to be more related to applications and how they functions rather than a question about networks, even if they do use a network. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you configure it to. Yes, that's possible.

Ideally the client is integrated into a router, and at the point it receives an IP from the ISP it can trigger an update, but if it's running on a computer inside the network all it can do is check regularly, and it can be wrong until the next check.

Comment: Correct.  But it can also be wrong because of DNS propegation.  If the DNS record has a TTL of 24 hours, you'll have to wait at least that long before requesting the new record.  So I would say your hostname can be wrong for a maximum duration of the interval/frequency your Dynamic DNS Client checks its own IP address, plus the TTL of your A record.